# SqlBulkCopy with Always Encrypted column

Tags: always-encrypted

I am importing CSV through .Net code and getting the data in data table and trying to bulk insert using SqlBulkCopy but i am getting certificate error. when i try to do the other operation there is no certificate error its only when i perform SqlBulkCopy. Here is error description

> Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider:
>   'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column
>   encryption key are: '7F-1D-20-E1-43-0B-B5-92-66-78'. Certificate with
>   thumbprint 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' not found in certificate store
>   'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate
>   path in the column master key definition in the database is correct,
>   and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate
>   location/store. Parameter name: masterKeyPath

i did the certificate import in local machine. below is code 
i have data in dt datatable object. that is returned from worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTableAsString.

```
Dim copy As New SqlBulkCopy(ConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.AllowEncryptedValueModifications)

copy.DestinationTableName = "Customer"
copy.ColumnMappings.Add("CustID", "CustID")
copy.ColumnMappings.Add("SSN", "SSN")
copy.WriteToServer(dt)
```

taking the reference  - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160577/is-it-possible-to-bulk-insert-data-into-a-table-that-has-columns-encrypted-with

if we go as per above we need to do the 2 round to insert the data.i have datatable object returned by Worksheet ExportDataTableAsString. when i directly use the datatable for SQLbulkcopy i get the the certificate missing error.

can someone help me on this and suggest better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on Certificate - All Tasks - Manage Private Keys -  Add user

IIS AppPool[DefaultAppPool] worked for me.